# Why aren't the bars on my graph D3.js appearing in the correct order?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble creating a side by side bar chart.

I will put here my code and an image of how the bars are not side by side in interspersed colors. I'm new to D3.js and have no idea why this is happening.

**Chart as it is now:**

[image]

In my jsonFile I have two salesmen, where it shows the sales history of each one. For example, I need to show in January the previous year's sales history of Seller A and Seller B, but as you can see in the image above this is not what is happening. The bars are in the wrong place.

**My HTML Code:**

```js
var sales = [
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
        "Vendas_Ano": 21611.950000000004,
        "Vendas_Ant": 16033.31
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
        "Vendas_Ano": 48108.08,
        "Vendas_Ant": 51142.299999999996
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
        "Vendas_Ano": 13427.280000000004,
        "Vendas_Ant": 21274.129999999997
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
        "Vendas_Ano": 28553.83,
        "Vendas_Ant": 15228.569999999998
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
        "Vendas_Ano": 19639.59,
        "Vendas_Ant": 10291.359999999999
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22530.840000000007,
        "Vendas_Ant": 21905.29
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
        "Vendas_Ano": 20216.759999999995,
        "Vendas_Ant": 8276
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
        "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
        "Vendas_Ant": 49810.810000000005
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Set",
        "Vendas_Ano": 12861.52,
        "Vendas_Ant": 24425.32
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Out",
        "Vendas_Ano": 9227.34,
        "Vendas_Ant": 17804.65
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 9993.34
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 36568.7
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22681.14,
        "Vendas_Ant": 28587.71
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
        "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
        "Vendas_Ant": 37637.420000000006
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
        "Vendas_Ano": 32453.779999999995,
        "Vendas_Ant": 32993.12
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
        "Vendas_Ano": 23445.4,
        "Vendas_Ant": 30835.75
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
        "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
        "Vendas_Ant": 18028.07
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
        "Vendas_Ano": 11617.470000000001,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22651.53
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
        "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
        "Vendas_Ant": 34152.28999999999
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
        "Vendas_Ano": 35476.94000000001,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22069.699999999997
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Set",
        "Vendas_Ano": 37462.92,
        "Vendas_Ant": 23120.08
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Out",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22042.140000000003,
        "Vendas_Ant": 28449.95
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 30755.050000000003
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22838.64
    }
]
var charnecaData = [];
    var joaoData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
        if (sales[i]["vendnm"] === "CHARNECA") {
            charnecaData.push(sales[i]);
        } else {
            joaoData.push(sales[i]);
        }
    }

    //functions for toggling between data
    function change(value) {
        if (value === 'lastYear') {
            update(charnecaData);
        } else if (value === 'currentYear') {
            update(joaoData);
        } else {
            update(sales);
        }
    }

    function update(data) {

        xChart.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.MonthAbrev; }));

        yChart.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.Vendas_Ant; })]);

        var barWidth = width / data.length;

        var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
            .remove()
            .exit()
            .data(data)

        bars.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return i * barWidth + 1 })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return yChart(d.Vendas_Ant); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yChart(d.Vendas_Ant); })
            .attr("width", barWidth - 5)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                if (d.vendnm === 'CHARNECA') {
                    return "rgb(251,180,174)";
                } else {
                    return "rgb(179,205,227)";
                }
            })
            .on("mouseover", function (a) {
                chart.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "title-text")
                    .style("fill", "rgb(44, 160, 44)")
                    .text(a.vendnm + ' - ' +
                        a.MonthAbrev + ' - ' +
                        Number(Math.round(a.Vendas_Ant * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) + '€'
                    )
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("x", 400)
                    .attr("y", 50);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (a) {
                chart.select(".title-text").remove();
            })

        //left axis
        chart.select('.y')
            .call(yAxis)
        //bottom axis
        chart.select('.xAxis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "rotate(-65)";
            });

    }//end update

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
    var width = 600;
    var height = 300;

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var xChart = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width]);

    var yChart = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xChart);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yChart);

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate(-65)";
        });

    update(sales);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style>
    .radio {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .row {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='radio'>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="lastYear" onclick='change(this.value)'> Last Year
                </label>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="currentYear" onclick='change(this.value)'> Current Year
                </label>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="both" onclick='change(this.value)' checked> Both
                </label>
            </div>
            <svg class='chart'>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As I said I'm new to D3.js, I'm doing this test based on this code: https://bl.ocks.org/syncopika/f1c9036b0deb058454f825238a95b6be

I've compared it several times to know what I'm doing wrong, but I can't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `scaleBand()` has a function to give you a width for each point:

`var barWidth = xChart.bandwidth()/2;`

And then you need to use `xChart()` function to get the `x` coordinate for every data point, instead of calculating it based on the index of a specific data point.

With minor adjustments of coordinates final result comes down to this line of code:

```
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return xChart(d.MonthAbrev) + barWidth*((d.vendnm == 'CHARNECA')?0.2:1) })
```

I hope this helps, let me know if it is not what you are looking for.

```js
var sales = [
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
        "Vendas_Ano": 21611.950000000004,
        "Vendas_Ant": 16033.31
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
        "Vendas_Ano": 48108.08,
        "Vendas_Ant": 51142.299999999996
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
        "Vendas_Ano": 13427.280000000004,
        "Vendas_Ant": 21274.129999999997
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
        "Vendas_Ano": 28553.83,
        "Vendas_Ant": 15228.569999999998
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
        "Vendas_Ano": 19639.59,
        "Vendas_Ant": 10291.359999999999
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22530.840000000007,
        "Vendas_Ant": 21905.29
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
        "Vendas_Ano": 20216.759999999995,
        "Vendas_Ant": 8276
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
        "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
        "Vendas_Ant": 49810.810000000005
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Set",
        "Vendas_Ano": 12861.52,
        "Vendas_Ant": 24425.32
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Out",
        "Vendas_Ano": 9227.34,
        "Vendas_Ant": 17804.65
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 9993.34
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 36568.7
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22681.14,
        "Vendas_Ant": 28587.71
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
        "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
        "Vendas_Ant": 37637.420000000006
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
        "Vendas_Ano": 32453.779999999995,
        "Vendas_Ant": 32993.12
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
        "Vendas_Ano": 23445.4,
        "Vendas_Ant": 30835.75
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
        "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
        "Vendas_Ant": 18028.07
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
        "Vendas_Ano": 11617.470000000001,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22651.53
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
        "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
        "Vendas_Ant": 34152.28999999999
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
        "Vendas_Ano": 35476.94000000001,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22069.699999999997
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Set",
        "Vendas_Ano": 37462.92,
        "Vendas_Ant": 23120.08
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Out",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22042.140000000003,
        "Vendas_Ant": 28449.95
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 30755.050000000003
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22838.64
    }
]
var charnecaData = [];
    var joaoData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
        if (sales[i]["vendnm"] === "CHARNECA") {
            charnecaData.push(sales[i]);
        } else {
            joaoData.push(sales[i]);
        }
    }

    //functions for toggling between data
    function change(value) {
        if (value === 'lastYear') {
            update(charnecaData);
        } else if (value === 'currentYear') {
            update(joaoData);
        } else {
            update(sales);
        }
    }

    function update(data) {

        xChart.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.MonthAbrev; }));

        yChart.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.Vendas_Ant; })]);

        var barWidth = xChart.bandwidth()/2;

        var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
            .remove()
            .exit()
            .data(data)

        bars.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return xChart(d.MonthAbrev) + barWidth*((d.vendnm == 'CHARNECA')?0.2:1) })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return yChart(d.Vendas_Ant); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yChart(d.Vendas_Ant); })
            .attr("width", barWidth - 5)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                if (d.vendnm === 'CHARNECA') {
                    return "rgb(251,180,174)";
                } else {
                    return "rgb(179,205,227)";
                }
            })
            .on("mouseover", function (a) {
                //console.log(a)
                chart.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "title-text")
                    .style("fill", "rgb(44, 160, 44)")
                    .text(a.vendnm + ' - ' +
                        a.MonthAbrev + ' - ' +
                        Number(Math.round(a.Vendas_Ant * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) + '€'
                    )
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("x", 400)
                    .attr("y", 50);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (a) {
                chart.select(".title-text").remove();
            })

        //left axis
        chart.select('.y')
            .call(yAxis)
        //bottom axis
        chart.select('.xAxis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "rotate(-65)";
            });

    }//end update

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
    var width = 600;
    var height = 300;

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var xChart = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width]);

    var yChart = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xChart);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yChart);

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate(-65)";
        });

    update(sales);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style>
    .radio {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .row {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='radio'>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="lastYear" onclick='change(this.value)'> Last Year
                </label>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="currentYear" onclick='change(this.value)'> Current Year
                </label>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="both" onclick='change(this.value)' checked> Both
                </label>
            </div>
            <svg class='chart'>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That´s works for me, now it´s perfect!!!! Thank you very much GSazheniuk!!!